# Prove: if $f:G\to H$ isomorphism there is $k:H \to G$ isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Prove: if $f:G\to H$ isomorphism there is $k:H \to G$ isomorphism

Isomorphism is an homomorphism which is $1-1$ and onto.

$f$ is

1. homomorphism: $\forall g_1,g_2\in G$ there are $h_1,h_2\in H$ s.t  $f(g_1\cdot g_2)=f(g_1)*f(g_2)$

2.1-1: $f(g_1)=f(g_2)\rightarrow g_1=g_2$

3. onto: for all $h\in H$ there is $g\in G$ s.t $f(g)=h$

$f$ is 1-1 and onto so there is $f^{-1}$ 1-1 and onto.

looking at$$g_1\cdot g_2=_{(1)}f^{-1}\large{[f(g_1\cdot g_2)]=f^{-1}[f(g_1)*f(g_2)]}=_{(2)}f^{-1}[h_1*h_2]$$

where $(1)$ $f$ is $inverse$ $(2)$ $f$ is $inverse$ and in particular onto.

So $k=f^{-1}$ is isomorphism

Is it valid? sorry for my wording

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is essentially correct.

Comment: Your condition at point (1) is not correct. $f:(G,\,\cdot\,)\to (H,*)$ is a homomorphism (of groups) if and only if $$\forall g_1,g_2\in G,\ f(g_1\cdot g_2^{-1})=f(g_1)*\left(f(g_2)\right)^{-1}$$ or, equivalently, if and only if $$\begin{cases}\forall g_1,g_2\in G,\ f(g_1\cdot g_2)=f(g_1)*f(g_2)\\ \forall g\in G,\ f(g^{-1})=(f(g))^{-1}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry, I had to mention it I started with the inner equation and with 1 move to the left and with 2 move to the right. tried to write it in a larger font

Answer (score 1):

You point out that $f^{-1}$ is a well-defined function which is 1-1 and onto, but you do not show this in any way (you just claim that this is true because $f$ is 1-1 and onto). I don't know whether you are required to do this in more detail, or if this is a previous result that you can rely on. In the latter case, then what you have is fine.

As for whether $f^{-1}$ is a homomorphism, you have more or less the right equalities written down, but they are in very strange order. Start with "$f^{-1}(h_1* h_2)=$" and end with "$=f^{-1}(h_1)\cdot f^{-1}(h_2)$". Also, being explicit that $h_1,h_2$ are two arbitrary elements of $H$, and that $g_1,g_2$ are elements of $G$ such that $f(g_1)=h_1$ and $f(g_2)=h_2$ might be a good idea. There are other small things to work on, but these are the most important ones in my opinion.